# WPF DataGridRow BorderThickness increase row's width

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want to display my data in DataGrid.
I wrote my style for it and here it is

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGreen" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="ForestGreen"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,0,0,0"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,6,0,0"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGreen"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGreen"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="ForestGreen"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGreen"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>    
</Style>
```

When i select the row the border show's up but the width of the row becomes larger than the width of the DataGrid -> I don't see right part of the border and horizontal scrollbar show's up.

So here is the question: how can i increase border thickness of the row, but do not increase row's width and height?

UPD
Before selection:

[image]

After selection:

[image]

Comment: Can you post screenshot before & after click. When Border Thickness is 1. Control will redraw as Border needs to take its required space/pixels (hence the resizing of row). One alternative would be to just change colors (Border Thickness is always 1) and resize the window a bit to accomodate this 1 extra pixel.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava i update my question by adding needed pictures. If i style my row with borderThincknes from the start, the row makes larger than the datagrid right at the start and i have horizontal scrol bar

Comment: As expected - the BorderThickness change causes slight increase in the width (hence that scrollbar appears). Either keep your View/Window size 1 pixel wider to accomodate this. Or Use border color change in trigger rather than Border Thickness for visual effect

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava is there any way to hold row's size in datagrid? this dataGrid is in the grid, and the size's of all of it are dynamicly change. So, i wanna my row not to resize itself with border

Comment: You have a margin in the datagridrow. Set that lower as you increase the border thickness.

Comment: @movorpovor - In your DataCell set MaxWidth -- that should stop cell size from resizing based on content size

Comment: @Andy it doesn't help

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava how can  I set width, if I want it to be as large as datagrid. So if datagrid will increase it's width, I want row to do exactly the same

Comment: @movorpovor -- Would it be possible for you to share your xaml (Bare minimum part) - that way I can see what fixes I can think of over it?

Comment: Sorry, I see that's a top margin now I look again. You have fixed width for all your columns?

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava https://github.com/movorpovor/troubleXaml

Comment: @Andy i don't understand what are you talking about

Comment: A datagridrow doesn't have a specific width, by default it just fills it's container and extends across the datagrid. It can end up bigger than that if what is going inside it demands more width. That could be because you just happen to have stuff in each column that exactly fills the datagrid. That seems unlikely. There is some reason it wants more space than you are giving it. The obvious explanation is you set a width to your columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
<ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
<ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
```

1st Column is Fixed Width 50 while the other 2 are of same width. This makes your window have narrow left margin but Grid Sized margin on the right. Change Column 3 Width = 50. If that is not how you want it, make both col 2 *& 3 width = * as that is same as being 5*.

Next, Your Grid Columns each have been assigned a Width as a proportion. When you resize the window then only you last column text gets chopped. Otherwise it appears nice & fine.

[image]

Comment: damn! i forgot, that i change my xaml, before add it to git. There is a mistake: i need border around all gridrow, but not around every cell, so in the code you need to move borderThickness setter from cell to row, I change the code at github, so you can grab from there. Anyway, I need those greed, that i described (50,5*,5*) and all other proportions, that i have

Answer (score -1):

Change DataGridRow style to following:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Border x:Name="DGR_Border" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <DataGridCellsPresenter ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" 
                                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                <DataGridDetailsPresenter Margin="4" 
                                                          Grid.Row="1" 
                                                          SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" 
                                                          Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"/>

                                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                        Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <DataGridRowHeader SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" 
                                               Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="DetailsVisibility" Value="Visible">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4,1,4,4"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF3886B9"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGreen"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="ForestGreen"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Hope this will resolve your problem...